# Is it possible to find out who donated troops to you

Tags: clash-of-clans

Sometimes we get donated troops that are different from what is requested within our clan. Is it possible to find out who donated the troops that is in the castle?

I know there is a brief notice appearing at the time the troops are donated if you are active at that time, but most of the time troops are donated when you are not active.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently the only time you know is upon donation. But you can also use other strategies to try to narrow down who the player is:

- What is your clan level? If it is level five plus but under ten, look for players that have the level equal to the level of the donated troops minus 1. If level 10, make that minus two. Apply only to players that can actually donate those troops
- Activity in clan chat. Those currently online are likely to chat and see if they could have donated the troops. Some key factors are that his army is partially complete: if you gave him back the troops he donated, his army would look the same and would fill up the remaining spaces
- People that are known to donate a certain troop/pattern. They should be checked if the troop(s) you received matches what he usually donates

The above strategies are not foolproof and you might end up kicking the wrong guy out...

Comment: Great input. I will also add one thing to potetially filter out. Look in the clan members list for people that has actually donated in the current period. Combined with looking at troop level, I was able to narrow it down to 4 people. Also I was able to rule out one that had only donated 6. Since the number now reflects housing space, it could not be him because the problem had donated 5 giants that takes 25 housing space.

Comment: First action would probably be to specify that in our clan it is expected that we respect request for specific troops. A good rule is that you don't request troops that are higher than your own level and type of troops unless it is for clan war. So if it is for clan war, say so in the request.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know you can only see the notification when the troops are actually donated to you.

Our clan tried to find this information out a while ago and never could find out who donated the troops after the fact.

Comment: I was afraid of that. It would be useful if you could click on the donated troops in the castle and get a popup with info on who donated it.

Comment: I know SuperCell released and API recently, but I am unsure whether it could give you that information.

Comment: One in our clan asked for Golems, and got Giants instead. He forgot to check the contents of the castle and thought he had got what he asked for, and his clan war attack was ruined.

Comment: Well he should have checked! ;)

Comment: Yes. Our top player commented on that also.

Comment: Historically people in our clan has been good at respecting requests, but lately we've had some strange donations.

Answer (score 2):

We finally was able to find out who donated wrong troops.

What finally solved it was that each time someone "caught him in the act" they posted a message in the clan chat about what he had done.

Then everyone knows each time he does it. Then we could establish that it was only this person each time, and eventually a leader kicked him out.

Answer (score -1):

What I like to do in my clan that I’m the leader of, in order to find who donated those wrong troops is go through everyone’s profile and see who has those same levels. I gather everyone who has those levels and pick which people that wouldn’t and which ones that probably would then I ask them and then give them a warning. The second time is and automatic kick!